# How to handle triangle in PDE to do separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Given is the hyperbolic PDE
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}-c^2 \triangle u=0$$
in the Domain $\Omega\times\Bbb{R}$ using the Dirichlet boundary condition $u=0$ in $\Omega\times\Bbb{R}$. The initial values of this PDE are the position $u(\vec x,t=0)=u_0(\vec x)$ and the velocity $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(\vec x,t=0)=u_1(\vec x)$

Show that it is possible to split the PDE into one ODE for the time $t$, and one eigenvalue equation
$$-\triangle X(x)=\lambda X(x)$$
for $x \in \Omega$ and $x=0$ in $\partial\Omega$ by using separation of variables.

I know that I have to put all the $t$'s on one side and all the $x$'s (or $\vec x$'s?) on the other side. For the beginning i have
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \triangle u$$

Let $u$ be in the form of $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=X(x)T''(t)$$
$$X(x)T''(t)=c^2 \cdot\triangle (X(x)T(t))$$
$$\frac{T''(t)}{c^2}=\frac{1}{X(x)}\cdot\triangle (X(x)T(t))$$

This is how far I got. Is this right? How do I handle the $\triangle$ to get the $T(t)$ from the right side to the left?

Comment: Do you know what is separation of variables in PDE?

Comment: Isn't it just to split the two variables and then integrate on each side?

Comment: No, that would be separation of variables in ODE. In PDE it refers to a different techniques.

Comment: I know that I can have $u$ in the form of $u(x,t)=v(x)q(t)$. But if I wanna substitute $u$ like this for example on the left side, how can I extract v so that I can get it to the right side? Also on the other side, how do I handle the $\triangle$?

Comment: I think I understand separation of variables in PDE now, but I just dont know how to handle the right side because of the $\triangle$.

Comment: I added the beginning of the separation to my question above.